# iframeElm.contentWindow.document.selection not working for <iframe> in IE if set focus on other input after making selection in the iframe

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, selection

This is similar but different question about how to set html in the selection of the iframe's editable content.

One sample found is: http://jsfiddle.net/HMRMv/1/, but it can also be used to show the problem.

On IE, in the sample if you select the text in iframe and then do the click, it will work.
But after select the text in the iframe's editable content and than clicking on other pane, you will see the highlight disappear and the 'click' on the button will do nothing. Look like the:

```
var range = document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.document.selection.createRange();
```

Cannot get the previous selected range.

I tried cache the range in blur and reuse it at the 'click', but it does not work. Is it to do with iframe, any suggestion on this case?

```
var selectedType, selectedRange;

function onBlur(e) {
    var selection = iframeElm.contentWindow.document.selection;
    var range = selection.createRange();

    selectedType= selection.type;
    selectedRange = range;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `blur` event is too late to cache the selection range because the selection is already destroyed by then. Use the IE-only [`beforedeactivate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/ms536903%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event on the iframe element instead.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HMRMv/34/

Comment: Thanks Tim! The beforedeactivate solution seems solve the problem. Wonder why IE destroys it when iframe becomes inactive and other browsers have the selection maintained.